# Trigger.io - splash screen disappears, but webview does not load until I tap the screen

Tags: android, kendo-ui, trigger.io

I've got an android trigger.io app, which I'm using a custom splash screen on.  Once this splash screen disappears, I sometimes am left with a black/grey gradient background while my webview has not loaded the content of my app (either a log on or a configuration page)

This seems to happen more often when I'm attempting to show a Kendo UI Modal Window immediately (I'm using one for a "Welcome to the app" first time message), and less frequently when this isn't shown.

Are there any known compatibility issues between Trigger and Kendo that I should be aware of to fix or work around this?

Comment: So the content shows if you tap the screen? What happens if you tap the screen right after the splash screen disappeared? I was also observing delayed UI refreshing until I tap the screen.. this was on Android 4.0.x devices. What devices/emulators are you testing on?

Comment: Rendering issues on Android 4.0.x devices can be caused by a hardware acceleration bug, you can disable hardware acceleration on 4.0.x using the requirements module: http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/requirements.html#android

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen on all Android devices, or only the ones with ICS (Android 4+)?

I had a similar problem on ICS.
It turned out that it was caused by CSS rule `-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0)`.